# How to access wordpress menu item through the REST API?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

I want to display the main menu items from Wordpress in another web-application. Therefor I need the content of `wp_nav_menu` exposed in the  REST API.

Is there a standard way to access the menu structure via API? If not, are there up to date plugins that cover this functionality? Google brought up only outdated solutions.

Answer (score 5):

Inspired by the proposal by baymax, I have created the following two functions, so it is possible to both get all available menus and to retrieve info about the individual menus.

Here are two functions that can be used to add the menu to the REST API and retrieve individual menu items. 
This allows us to access both:
https://your-wp-domain-url.com/wp-json/custom/menu and
[https://your-wp-domain-url.com/wp-json/custom/menu/{menuID}](https://your-wp-domain-url.com/wp-json/custom/menu/%7BmenuID%7D)

```
// Menu locations
add_action( 'rest_api_init', function() {
        register_rest_route( 'custom', '/menu/', array(
        'methods' => 'GET',
        'callback' => 'wp_menu_route',
    ));
});

function wp_menu_route() {
    $menuLocations = get_nav_menu_locations(); // Get nav locations set in theme, usually functions.php)
    return $menuLocations;
}

// Individual menus
add_action( 'rest_api_init', function() {
    register_rest_route( 'custom', '/menu/(?P<id>\d+)', array(
        'methods' => 'GET',
        'callback' => 'wp_menu_single',
    ));
});

function wp_menu_single($data) {
    $menuID = $data['id']; // Get the menu from the ID
    $primaryNav = wp_get_nav_menu_items($menuID); // Get the array of wp objects, the nav items for our queried location.
    return $primaryNav;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

How about this. You can access your "Primary" menu using this route ->
https://your-wp-domain-url.com/wp-json/custom-name/menu

And make sure to use your Primary menu from register_nav_menus().
In my WP Theme at functions.php I have these lines.(***'menu-1'*** is my primary menu)

```
register_nav_menus( array(
    'menu-1' => esc_html__( 'Primary', 'text-domain' ),
));
```

Add this ***'menu-1'*** in this line

===>  **$menuID = $menuLocations['*menu-1*'];**

```
//https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_nav_menu_items/
function wp_menu_route() {

        // register_nav_menus( array(
        //     'menu-1' => esc_html__( 'Primary', 'text-domain' ),
        // ) );

    // using register_nav_menus primary menu name -> 'menu-1'
    $menuLocations = get_nav_menu_locations(); // Get nav locations set in theme, usually functions.php)
                                               // returns an array of menu locations ([LOCATION_NAME] = MENU_ID);

    $menuID = $menuLocations['menu-1']; // Get the *primary* menu added in register_nav_menus()
    $primaryNav = wp_get_nav_menu_items($menuID); // Get the array of wp objects, the nav items for our queried location.
    return $primaryNav;

}

add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {
        //https://your-wp-domain-url.com/wp-json/custom-name/menu
        register_rest_route( 'custom-name', '/menu', array(
        'methods' => 'GET',
        'callback' => 'wp_menu_route',
    ) );
} );
```

Answer (score -1):

first step: install WP-REST-API V2 Menus
https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-rest-api-v2-menus/

second step:
Domain-name/wp-json/menus/v1/menus list of every registered menu.
Domain-name/wp-json/menus/v1/menus/slug data for a specific menu.

Comment: I installed the plugin, but I get a 404 with {"code": "rest_no_route"}.

Comment: Which URL are you run?

Comment: Make sure it is .../wp-json/menus/v1/menus